# Deploying an ASP.NET website Solution with multiple projects under it 

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, deployment, web-deployment-project

I am trying to upload an asp.net website project with multiple solution within, for example one solution is for Data Access Layer and others are Business Logic Layer, UI, commonUtilities..

Locally it is working fine but when I upload file in the remote server it shows nothing expect if I only upload User Interface separately where there are aspx files stored. 
It also does not show publish option when I right click on the main solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One Correction, This is wrong : You have multiple Solutions under a WebSite project.

You have a Visual Studio **Solution with multiple projects under it** including the UI project, Data Access project, class libraries etc...

You should be publishing the **UI project** only( where you have the ASPX files). Right click on that specific project and you will see the publish option in the context menu. Your other projects will be compiled to an assembly (**DLL** file) and will be available in a folder called bin when you publish it (*Assuming you have proper references added to these projects in your UI projects references section*) . Move those files (the ASPX files, bin folder, Any folders where you have the Scripts/CSS) to your server and you will be good.

Comment: Thank you very much, but I do get another error which is: "Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information" what is solution for it, Do I have to  set the Copy Local property to True if so I am unable to find that option in Visual Studio please advise?

Comment: @user998007 : Yes right click on reference and select properties and set `TRUE` value to `CopyLocal` Proeprty. That will copy the referenced DLL to Bin folder

Comment: Thank you very much indeed. Should I do this process(setting TRUE value) to all references one by one to all projects in the solution or only where web files(aspx) are located. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user998007 Setting this for the  references in the UI project should be good

Comment: If I have a solution with a MVC 4 Internet Project. What kind of project do I have to add for Data (Model, DAL) ? And if I want to add a RDLC report project ?

Comment: @Misi : You can add class library type project for that

Comment: When I'm trying to add a Controller for an entity(TableName1) I get this error : _'Unable to retrive metadata for 'ClassLibrary1.TableName1'. The specified named connection is either not found in the configuration, not inteneded to be used with the EntityClient provider, or not valid.'_. I've added reference in my MVC project.

Comment: @Misi: Please post as a new question with relevant details.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13290973/splitting-an-empty-solution-into-multiple-projects

Answer (score 1):

If your web application is referencing the other projects, Visual Studio will deploy their DLLs along with the web application/user interface.

HTH