# Splitting an Solution into multiple projects

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, entity-framework, projects-and-solutions

I created a Black Solution (Arhi) with a ASP.NET MVC 4 Internet project (Arhi.Core) and Class library project for data (Arhi.Data) where I'm storing my EDMX Model.

I added a reference for Arhi.Data into Arhi.Core and I tried to add a Controller with a Model class from Arhi.Data (People entity) and I got this error.

> 'Unable to retrive metadata for 'Arhi.Core.People'. The specified
>   named connection is either not found in the configuration, not
>   inteneded to be used with the EntityClient provider, or not valid.'

**Q** : Why did I get this error ? Is my approach wrong / any recommendations?
Q2 : If I want to add RDLC reports to my solution, should I also use a Class Library project ?

Connection string from Arhi.Core

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=aspnet-SalvamontMVC-20121108140556;Integrated Security=SSPI" />
```

and Arhi.Data

```
<add name="SalvamontEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/ModelSalva.csdl|res://*/ModelSalva.ssdl|res://*/ModelSalva.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=www.arhimedes.ro,1433;initial catalog=Salvamont;persist security info=True;user id=sa;password=********;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Comment: C/P your connection string from data project(App.Config) to Core project (Web.Config)

Comment: I've posted(above) my 2 connection strings.

Comment: copy paste conn string "SalvamontEntities" to Arhi.Core, and repost if error preserves.

Comment: I managed to add my controller but I had to add <add assembly="System.Data.Entity in the web.config so it would display data.

Comment: If I want to add another project to my solution for reports do I need to copy in web.config connection string from Arhi.Data ?

Comment: Yes. I recommend reading http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/ee712907

Answer (score 0):

in your first connection string  not  have user name  and password if two database deference then give user name and password in first connection string